# Multiple git repositories in same path

Tags: git

So, I've checked around and read a bit about submodules and other tricks to handle this, but I'm unsure whether it really addresses my need. Here is my current git repo of my content management system:

```
/Atlas
/Atlas/Core
/Sites
/Sites/site1
/Sites/site2
```

Simplified, of course. But "Core" is the folder with all the code for the CMS, and "/Sites" is a folder that has a subfolder for each site. I have added all sites under /Sites but some are excluded by .gitignore

Now, some of those excluded are those that aren't client-related. Personal sites that run in the same structure. What I need now is for me to have a git repository where I can check out, edit and push changes to these personal sites, that not all developers need access to. So .gitignore has:

```
/Sites/site3
```

For instance, but I need to checkout site3, edit it and push it back out to the server without it being included in the aforementioned repo. Is this possible with submodules? Or do I need some other method?

Comment: Yes, you want to use submodules. https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules

Answer (score 0):

It would seem that you could solve this using simple branches, one for each site.

Normally I would suggest against long-running feature branches, but if I understand your problem correctly, you don't ever intend to merge these back into your master branch. In that case, the only merges you would ever need to do are master -> site3, and no other developers will ever need to pull the changes you make in your site3 branch.

When you push this branch to the remote server, it will be visible to your developers (potentially useful for collaboration), but not be included in their git pulls when they just want to update their local copy of master.

The only issue I can see with this is if your Content Management System is unable to load separate sites from separate remote branches.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Branches seem unintuitive since /Sites/site3 is included in the .gitignore file, right?